Showing Heisenberg uncertainty relation implies determinant of covariance matrix is bounded below
Let $p$ and $q$ be canonical observables with some fixed state $\rho$. Define the mean value $$\langle A \rangle_\rho = \text{Tr}(A\rho) $$ Then, we define the covariance matrix $\Gamma$ to be $\Gamma_{1,1} = \langle p^2 \rangle_\rho$, $\Gamma_{2,2} = \langle q^2 \rangle_\rho$, and $\Gamma_{1,2} = \Gamma_{2,1} = \langle \frac{pq + qp}{2} \rangle_\rho$.
In this paper on page $458$, the authors state that $\det(\Gamma) \geq \frac{\hbar^2}{4}$ is an easy consequence of the Heisenberg uncertainty relation $$\Delta p \Delta q \geq \frac{\hbar}{2} $$ where $(\Delta A)^2 = \langle A^2 \rangle_\rho - \langle A\rangle^2_\rho$ However, I am unable to see this.
A trivial bound applying $\langle A \rangle_\rho^2 \leq \langle A ^2\rangle_\rho$ (for self adjoint $A$) and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $|\langle AB \rangle_\rho |^2 \leq \langle A^2 \rangle_\rho \langle B^2 \rangle_\rho$ yields $$\frac{\hbar^2}{4} \leq (\Delta p)^2(\Delta q)^2 \leq \langle p^2 \rangle_\rho \langle q^2\rangle_\rho - \langle p \rangle_\rho^2\langle q \rangle_\rho^2 $$
Moreover, it can be seen that as $pq = \frac{pq + qp}{2} - \frac{i\hbar}{2}$, $$\det(\Gamma) \geq \langle p ^2\rangle_\rho \langle q^2 \rangle_\rho - |\langle pq \rangle_\rho|^2 $$
by using the fact that $$\langle \frac{pq + qp}{2} \rangle_\rho^2 \leq |\langle\frac{pq+qp}{2}\rangle_\rho - \frac{i\hbar}{2}|^2 .$$
But I am unable to progress any further. Is there a trick I'm missing relating these quantities?

Have you tried to use the stronger version of the HUP?

@TobiasFünke No, I'll look into that.

See in particular this.
